# How to create custom category attribute with wysiwyg editor in magento2?

Tags: magento2, wysiwyg, category-attribute

Hi i want to add custom category attribute with wysiwyg enable editor i get the code of custom category attribute but not able to find with wysiwyg editor.if anyone is there help me please.

Comment: Did you enabled attribute wysiwyg value. Please check URL http://inchoo.net/magento-2/add-category-attribute-magento-2/

Comment: yes i enabled but its not working..and i also follow all steps of inchoo which link you gave me.

Comment: Okay Can you please check added attribute in your db catalog_eav_attribute table
is_wysiwyg_enabled and is_html_allowed_on_front, it should be 1

Answer (score 6):

Please follow the below steps to create a custom Category attribute and add it as WYSIWYG Editor in Category form.

**Step 1: Create custom attribute through Install or Upgrade Script.**

Below is an example of an install script.

> Namespace/Modulename/Setup/InstallData.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Namespace\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Setup\CategorySetupFactory;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{

    public function __construct( CategorySetupFactory $categorySetupFactory )
    {
        $this->categorySetupFactory = $categorySetupFactory;
    }
    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {

        $setup->startSetup();

        $categorySetup = $this->categorySetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        $categorySetup->addAttribute(
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category::ENTITY, 'category_custom_editor', [
                'type' => 'text',
                'label' => 'Custom Editor',
                'input' => 'textarea',
                'backend' => 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Backend\ArrayBackend',
                'wysiwyg_enabled' => true,
                'is_html_allowed_on_front' => true,
                'required' => false,
                'sort_order' => 10,
                'global' => ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE
            ]
        );

         $setup->endSetup();

     }
 }
```

Run  **php bin/magento setup:upgrade** console command to upgrade your data. Now your custom attribute will be created.

**Step 2: Add the Custom attribute in Category Form with WYSIWYG Editor**

> Namespace/ModuleName/view/adminhtml/ui_component/category_form.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <fieldset name="content">
        <field name="category_custom_editor" template="ui/form/field" sortOrder="10" formElement="wysiwyg">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="wysiwygConfigData" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="settings" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="theme_advanced_buttons1" xsi:type="string">bold,italic,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,|,fontselect,fontsizeselect,|,forecolor,backcolor,|,link,unlink,image,|,bullist,numlist,|,code</item>
                            <item name="theme_advanced_buttons2" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                            <item name="theme_advanced_buttons3" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                            <item name="theme_advanced_buttons4" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                            <item name="theme_advanced_statusbar_location" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                        </item>
                        <item name="height" xsi:type="string">10px</item>
                        <item name="toggle_button" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                        <item name="add_variables" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        <item name="add_widgets" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                        <item name="add_images" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        <item name="add_directives" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">category</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <settings>
                <scopeLabel>[STORE VIEW]</scopeLabel>
                <label translate="true">Custom Editor</label>
                <dataScope>category_custom_editor</dataScope>
            </settings>
            <formElements>
                <wysiwyg class="Magento\Catalog\Ui\Component\Category\Form\Element\Wysiwyg">
                    <settings>
                        <rows>4</rows>
                        <wysiwyg>true</wysiwyg>
                    </settings>
                </wysiwyg>
            </formElements>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Clear the cache if you have enabled it. Now you can see your custom editor attribute in  Admin Category edit form.

Comment: Not showing in admin area but it's in the eav_attribute table any help

Comment: How to get this value on frontend?

Comment: How show this attribute value on frontend

Answer (score 2):

If the editor is not showing after the following advice above, make sure you have installed the attribute with `is_wysiwyg_enabled => true`, else it won't show (tested in 2.4.1)

Example:

```
<?php

    namespace Vendor\Module\Setup;

    use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface;
    use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
    use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
    use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
    use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

    class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
    {
        private $eavSetupFactory;

        public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory)
        {
            $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
        }

        public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
        {
            if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '0.1.0') < 0) {
                $setup->startSetup();
                $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
               
                $eavSetup->addAttribute(
                    Category::ENTITY,
                    'description_bottom',
                    [
                        'type'                      => 'text',
                        'label'                     => 'Description Bottom',
                        'input'                     => 'textarea',
                        'required'                  => false,
                        'sort_order'                => 120,
                        'global'                    => ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
                        'is_wysiwyg_enabled'        => true,
                        'is_html_allowed_on_front'  => true,
                        'group'                     => 'General Information',
                    ]
                );
                $setup->endSetup();
            }
        }
    }
```

This is working `category_form.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <fieldset name="content">
        <field name="description_bottom">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">150</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">string</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">wysiwyg</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Description Bottom</item>
                    <item name="notice" xsi:type="string" translate="true"></item>
                    <item name="additionalClasses" xsi:type="string"></item>
                    <item name="class" xsi:type="string">Magento\Catalog\Ui\Component\Category\Form\Element\Wysiwyg</item>
                    <item name="wysiwygConfigData" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="settings" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="theme_advanced_buttons1" xsi:type="string">bold,italic,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,|,fontselect,fontsizeselect,|,forecolor,backcolor,|,link,unlink,image,|,bullist,numlist,|,code</item>
                            <item name="theme_advanced_buttons2" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                            <item name="theme_advanced_buttons3" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                            <item name="theme_advanced_buttons4" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                            <item name="theme_advanced_statusbar_location" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                        </item>
                        <item name="files_browser_window_url" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                        <item name="height" xsi:type="string">100px</item>
                        <item name="toggle_button" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        <item name="add_variables" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                        <item name="add_widgets" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                        <item name="add_images" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/form/field</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">category</item>
                    <item name="wysiwyg" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="rows" xsi:type="number">8</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```